# SIS r Error in glm.fit(cbind(ones, x[, index], x[, condind]), y, family = gaussian()) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Tags: r, sis

I am using SIS  R. My data is numerical including the response variable. 
It has 651 Columns. I standardized it and convert it to matrix form.

library("SIS")

```
model1 <- SIS(GTGTm, gGTym, family = "gaussian", penalty = "lasso",
              tune = "bic", nfolds = 10,perm = FALSE,varISIS= "cons",  nsis = 10,
              standardize = TRUE)
```

I don't have any NA in the data.  But I am getting the following error message.  Please help! But,it is creating the space with as.matrix so I don't know how to fix it.

```
GT = read.csv("train.csv")
GTy = read.csv("trainy.csv")

x <- as.matrix(GT[,])
y <- as.matrix(GTy[,])

With str(x)
 chr [1:129, 1:651] " 44" " 55" " 58" " 39" "100" " 85" " 38" " 58" " 80" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:651] "Automotive.Industry" "Commercial.Vehicles" "Motorcycles" "SUVs" ...
```

model1 <- SIS(GTGTm, gGTym, family = "gaussian", penalty = "lasso",
+               tune = "bic", nfolds = 10,perm = FALSE,varISIS= "cons",  nsis = 10,
+               standardize = TRUE)
Iter 1 , screening:  62 191 212 223 227 237 
Iter 1 , selection:  191 212 227 
Error in glm.fit(cbind(ones, x[, index], x[, condind]), y, family = gaussian()) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "numeric" : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it is better to use data.matrix instead of as.matrix.